# PyQt4 Label not showing

Tags: python, oop, pyqt4

I am very new to PyQt4 and this question is probably very simple but I have tried many different things and nothing works. I am trying to make a label in PyQt4.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Display(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Display, self).__init__()
         self.time = Time()       #Another class in the program
         self.ShowFullScreen()
         self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
         self.show()
         self.MainDisplay()

    def MainDisplay(self):
        self.timedisplay = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.timedisplay.setStyleSheet("font: 30pt Helvetica; color: white;")
        self.timedisplay.setText(time.GetTime())
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Display()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The label doesn't show up, and there is no error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use PySide and not Qt, but they are supposed to be 99.99% compatible.  The main problem is your call to the `show()` function, which makes the window visible.  You have two calls to `show`.  The first time it is called, you have not yet called `MainDisplay` so the `QLabel` hasn't been created yet.  The second time you call `show` the window is *already* visible, so nothing changes.

If you create the widgets first and call `show` once, at the end, it will work the way you want.  With this code the label shows up.

There are other issues:

You will have to change the import statements back the way you had them.

I did not have your Time class, so I just wrote a simple piece of text into the label.

The function `ShowFullScreen` should be `showFullScreen`.

The function that runs the event loop in QtApp is named `exec_` not `exec`.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore
from PySide import QtGui

class Display(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
         super(Display, self).__init__()
         self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
         self.MainDisplay()
         self.showFullScreen()

    def MainDisplay(self):
        self.timedisplay = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.timedisplay.setStyleSheet("font: 30pt Helvetica; color: white;")
        self.timedisplay.setText("What time is it now?")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Display()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There is no `ShowFullScreen()` but if there is `showFullScreen()`

Comment: Using `show()` and `showFullScreen()` many times is unnecessary, only the last of these commands will be effective

Comment: It still doesn't work. I even copied and pasted your code into a new file(changing out PySide for PyQt4), and I just get a black window with no label.

Comment: You may have been confused by the edit I made after testing the code.  In the version I tested the line showFullScreen was commented out, and I put it back in without testing it after eyllanesc pointed out the correct function name.  The line showFullScreen should be moved to the last line of `__init__`.  I explained the principle in my answer and eyllanesc also mentioned it.  I will re-edit again.